# img does not resize on window srhink

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code setting two pictures side by side and should shrink when pages shrinks, but this doesn't work.

I got rid of every class on parent divs, but still nothing...

Any idea why pictures do not shrink when browser window shrinks??

Thanks

```css
.align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    z-index: -100;
}
.navigate {
    margin: -10px 888px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.leftSide {
    height: 558px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 344px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.rightSide {
    height: 558px;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px 1053px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.verticalLine {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 558px;
    margin: -557px 940px;
}
img {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
    <div class="navigate"> <a id="prevPic" href="#">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
 <a id="nextPic" href="#">Next&gt;&gt;</a>

    </div>
    <div class="leftSide">
        <img id="leftPhoto" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121205063258/disney/images/7/71/Donald-duck-disney-photo-450x400-dcp-cpna013154.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="verticalLine"></div>
    <div class="rightSide">
        <img id="rightPhoto" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121205063258/disney/images/7/71/Donald-duck-disney-photo-450x400-dcp-cpna013154.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.align {
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}
.container{
 width:90%;
 height:568px;
 display:inline-block;
 }
.navigate {
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:20px;
}
.leftSide {
 margin:0;
 height: auto;
 max-height:100%;
 width:49%;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
}
.rightSide {
 margin:0;
 height: auto;
 max-height:100%;
 width:49%;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
}
.verticalLine {
 width: 1px;
 background-color: red;
 height: 558px;
 display:inline-block;
 
}
.leftSide img {
 width:auto;
 max-width:100%;

}
.rightSide img {
 width:auto;
 max-width:100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="align">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigate"> <a id="prevPic" href="#">&lt;&lt; Prev</a> <a id="nextPic" href="#">Next&gt;&gt;</a> </div>
  <div class="leftSide"> <img id="leftPhoto" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121205063258/disney/images/7/71/Donald-duck-disney-photo-450x400-dcp-cpna013154.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="verticalLine"></div>
  <div class="rightSide"> <img id="rightPhoto" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121205063258/disney/images/7/71/Donald-duck-disney-photo-450x400-dcp-cpna013154.jpg"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add these two attributes to the div class,

```
 .div_class
  {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
```